# How can I select rows from a datatable based on IDs from another table

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, datatable

I am looking for something like this

> student1.select( those records if the ids exists in student2 table)

I am looking for non-LINQ solution but Linq solution will be helpful as well.

***Example***

```
Student1 (Table)
Id    Name    Score
1     Joe     80
2     Mike    90
3     Sale    70
4     Ma      80
5     Jill    80


Student2 (table)
Id    Name    Score
1     Joe     80
5     Jill    80
```

I want to select only record 1 and 5 from table1  based on data in table2

Comment: Just to clarify: You want to query the resulting data for the follwing SQL query? `select * from Student1 where Id in (select Id from Student2)`

Answer (score 0):

This is called a join.  You do it like this:

```
select *
from student1
join student2 on student1.id = student2.id
```

Linq:

```
var result = student1.Where(s1 => student2.Any(s2 => s2.id == s1.id))
                     .Select( /* data you want here */);
```

Comment: I am looking for query against datatable, sorry.

Comment: @Nick - What the heck did you mean by this "I am looking for non-LINQ solution"?

Comment: I am not an expert on .NET but I was looking for query inside C# code (not an SQL query). Not sure if only LINQ can do it or can be done otherwise. As the question says `datatable.select(..this part needed....)`

Comment: @Nick - if you are using `<anything>.Select` then it is linq.  Note, `Select` is case sensitive.  In any case I added that additional information to the answer above.

Comment: Right, I am only looking for the second part. Have to play with this when  get a chance. I used a different approach in my original problem.